# Reloading an <object> html tag in AugularJS

Tags: html, .net, angularjs, url

I'm working on a web project where it requires a user to upload a pdf file, what I found was when the user deletes a file that they uploaded before and tries to upload a new file, in the preview mode it is still the deleted file that can be seen. The preview page is rendered in an object tag so I'm trying to figure out a way to reload it.

Here's my angular code in the controller:

```
    var getFile= function () {
        service.getFile()  // c# endpoint
            .then(function (response) {
                var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                $scope.fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            })
            .catch(function (fallback) {
                $scope.fileURL = null;
            });
    }
```

As far as I understand, the normal Angular behavior is whenever the {{fileURL}} changes, the watcher should update the html accordingly. However, in my HTML code below,

```
<h3>{{fileURL}}</h3>
<div id="pdfFile">
      <object type="application/pdf" data="{{fileURL}}" width="100%" height="1000"></object>
</div>
```

The {{fileURL}} in  gets updated correctly while the {{fileURL}} as the data attribute stays the same. I can confirm that from the backend the correct file data has been transmitted along the way.

I've tried to use jQuery to grab the object tag and set its data attribute directly, what I've found in that approach is that the {{fileURL}}'s value in the controller is different from the one used in the HTML code, but they point to the same file. I think this is due to the fact that those URLs are temporarily generated, so the scope is limited.

I've also tried this:

```
     var $pdf = $("#pdfFile");
     console.log("Step 1");
     $pdf.empty();
     console.log("Step 2");
     var newObj = '<object type="application/pdf" data="{{fileURL}}" width="100%" height="1000" id="pdfFile"></object>'
     console.log("Step 3");
     $pdf.append(newObj);
     console.log("Step 4");
```

but this has the same issue as the last approach, it points to an invalid url and just returns me to the home page of my application.

The $route.reload() method is not desirable, and the $scope.apply() method would not work. I'm confused as of why the object tag does not change accordingly and how I should fix this.

Please give me some advice on how to tackle this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `service.getFile()` using angular `$http`?

Comment: @charlietfl yes it is. But I checked the database and can confirm that the file data transmitted all the way till the getFile() is correct.

Comment: The jQuery approach won't work because when you insert angular directives or interpolation  you first have to use `$compile()` which takes scope as an argument to *"register"* in angular app. Not sure what else to suggest yet

Comment: Is the same `serivce.getFile()` used to load initial pdf?

Comment: One other thing crossed my mind. Is this inside nested child scope(s) ... `ng-if`, ,  `ng-repeat` or `ng-include` etc?

Comment: @charlietfl yes the service.getFile() is called every time a user loads a pdf. This is a child tag of a ng-show div, I think that does not matter because the rest of the content does show in the page. One more question, although I can confirm that the file data is correct, could we in this case eliminate the back-end as the source of error completely? I'm new to angular and not sure if there are other intricacies involved.

Comment: Yes you can use FileReader API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll erase this if I'm misunderstanding the problem, but have you tried a combination of `ng-if` (not `ng-show`) and some kind of switch using a timeout. `ng-if` will completely remove the object from the dom whereas `ng-show` only hides it.

```
<div id="pdfFile">
      <object type="application/pdf"  ng-if="fileURL" data="{{fileURL}}" width="100%" height="1000"></object>
</div>
```

... then in the controller

Make sure you're injecting the $timeout and $window objects

```
angular.module('controllers.myController', [])
    .controller('myController', [
    "$scope",
    "$rootScope",
    "$stateParams",
    "$timeout",
    "$window",
    function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $timeout, $window) {
       ....
```

Then in your code...

```
.then(function (response) {
                var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                $scope.fileURL = null;
                $timeout(() => { $scope.fileURL = $window.URL.createObjectURL(file); }, 500);
            })
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the point of this is to set fileURL to null to remove the object, then to set it back to a valid value so that the object gets refreshed to a new one?

Comment: Yes, the point is to remove the element from the DOM, then add it back. it seemed like the issue was you were not able to update the object embed by changing the fileURL value. This will force the page to rerender the object component

Comment: I think this does not work and it throws an exception. The div with id "pdfFile" is inside another ng-show div.

Comment: I just moved the `ng-if` to be in the object tag, rather than the surrounding `div` - how does that work?

Comment: I think the problem lies in the javascript code, in particular the timeout function. I'm not sure how that throws an error (this might be the same reason as of why the object tag doesn't get reloaded). I'm digging around to figure out the reason now.

Comment: I updated my answer. Do you have the `$timeout` method getting injected? I also updated the answer to use  `$window`  rather than `window` just in case that was part of the problem.What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly now as expected. I'll upvote your answer as soon as I hit 15 reputation.

Comment: go ahead and accept it as the answer in the meanwhile, thx